# How do I keep Resharper from massively indenting lambdas?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper, autoformatting

I have Resharper installed with mainly default settings. Currently, I'd like my multi-line lambda expressions to look something like this:

```
foobarclass.biz.baz.Event += (s, e) =>
  {
    foo.Bar.DoThings.Whatever();
  };
```

However, Resharper "helpfully" will reformat my code to be like this:

```
foobarclass.biz.baz.Event += (s, e) =>
                                 {
                                     foo.Bar.DoThings.Whatever();
                                 };
```

And in some cases, will also break up long statements so it ends up looking like this:

```
foobarclass.biz.baz.Event += (s, e) =>
                                 {
                                     foo.
                                        Bar.
                                        DoThings.
                                        Whatever();
                                 };
```

As you can tell, this auto-formatting makes code a lot *less* readable. How can I fix this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try unchecking:

> RESHARPER -> OPTIONS -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other -> Indent Anonymous Method Body

Comment: It appears to be a combination of this and changing the braces layout

Comment: Though I hate GNU style for most things, for anonymous methods it does what I want

Comment: Updated response... this seems to do what you want.

Comment: Using Resharper 8 and this option not found anymore. Still suffering from the crazy indentation. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'll look and get back to you ;)

Comment: @g.pickardou The option is simply called "Anonymous Method Body" now and is located under the "Align Multiline Constructs" header.

Comment: The seems to work with the ReSharper (such as when I do Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D, but then if I delete the closing brace and type it again, the indentation is back, so I am wondering if VS is doing it. Everything was working great until I installed VS 2015 and the updated ReSharper... the search continues!

Comment: @hvaughan3 I believe that in that case it's VS doing the indentation and not R#. R#'s rules are applied when you do a code cleanup; so if you do that and your code looks good then it's VS causing issues.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Have not been able to figure out which setting in VS it is but will report back when I find the issue. Thanks for getting back to me!

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I found this because I had the same problem with resharper 2016.2. And changing this setting did nothing, the example code did not even change when ticking and unticking the box.

I had to enable the "Use old formatting engine" option under other>other for lambdas to not become massively indented.

Comment: @ErikNilsson: apparently it's a regression: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-460614