# Resharper C++ Lambda Braces Indentation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper-c++

I am using Resharper C++.

I have code that often uses lambdas as function parameters, and I want them aligned as such:

```
return Method(
    [&]() -> bool
    {
        return this.variable >= 0;
    },
    "a normal parameter");
```

i.e. I want all parameters aligned on *"one clear vertical line"*.

However, Resharper will align it as such:

```
return Method(
    [&]() -> bool
{
    return this.variable >= 0;
},
    "a normal parameter");
```

Which is obviously far less readably (especially when working with functions that use many lambdas and many "normal" parameters.

Neither

> RESHARPER -> Options -> C++ -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout -> Other statements and blocks

nor

> RESHARPER -> Options -> C++ -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout -> Other braces

seemed to work (or work without undesired side effects).

I am looking for a solution as described here: [Resharper C# lambda indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846409/how-do-i-keep-resharper-from-massively-indenting-lambdas) but I can't seem to find one for Resharper C++.

Now, my questions are:

1. Is the way I want to indent the braces a common approach or should I look for another?
2. How can I accomplish that particular formatting (if it is possible at all)?

Thank in advance you for your help

Comment: One question per question please. That's (roughly) my indentation style too. Make a feature request to the Resharper team - not really an SO q

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, I thought so too. Thank you nevertheless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in ReSharper's formatting logic. I filed [RSCPP-19853](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-19853), it should be fixed in the next release. Please vote for the issue to receive updates.