# How to configure ReSharper to keep parameters of embedded lambdas on first line

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm trying to improve consistency within my team's codebase and to do this I'm putting together a team-shared R# configuration. However, I find that this codebase  prefers this sort of style for embedding lambdas:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Foo", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new Bar()));
});
```

Whereas ReSharper reformats this code like:

```
services.AddAuthorization(
    options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Foo", policy =>
            policy.Requirements.Add(new Bar()));
    });
```

Is there a way I can configure R# to enforce the original style?

**Edit**

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2017 (v15.9.10)
- ReSharper Ultimate 2018.3.4

Comment: Are you looking for this [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13846524/2451726) ?

Comment: @Arulkumar I saw that earlier, but I think that answer is outdated (my R# only has "revert to old formatting engine" under "Other"). One of the comments under it mentions "Anonymous Method Body" but this option is already unchecked, and it makes no difference if I check it.

Comment: Please mention your R# and Visual Studio version in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the option you are trying to find is under:
`R# > Options > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Arrangement of Expression Bodied Members`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot tomorrow.

Comment: I don’t see any options in that category that seem to help unfortunately

Comment: Then I see there is no option to do it. However there is still one option under the same place you should try, which is `Arrangement of Embedded Blocks`

Comment: Nothing there either, it even carries on reformatting the code to the style I don’t want after selecting the “keep existing arrangement” option. I’ll probably have to raise a ticket with them.

Comment: If that doesn't help maybe an option would be tell to your team by a custom pattern in Code Inspection to change it accordinly to what you want. -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html